# gitblit jenkins.groovy not triggered

Tags: groovy, jenkins, git-post-receive

I have modified the jenkins.groovy script to add the url for my jenkins server. However the build job in jenkins does not start when code is pushed to gitblit. If I type the trigger url in the browser

```
e.g http://localhost:8080/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<gitblit-url>
```

then the build in jenkins runs [so I'm ruling out jenkins as the culprit]

The jenkins.groovy script has a line like

```
logger.info("jenkins hook triggered by ${user.username} for ${repository.name}")
```

however I cannot find anything similar in catalina.out

How can I find out why the hook script is not being triggered?

**What I have tried:**

- Running gitblit in debug mode. The logs were more verbose, yes, but still nothing relating to the hook script

Any ideas?

Gitblit and Jenkins are running on the same server(RHEL6.5) in Tomcat6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be GitBlit tickets. If I turn the ticket service off, the hook script works. Turn it back on and the hook script doesn't work. Tried File based tickets and Branch based tickets just to be sure.